# How to convert a urlcode in array in php?

Tags: php, jquery

I hope you can help me;

How to convert a urlcode in array in php?

example:

```
$Urlcode = 'name=luiz&country=Brazil&city=patrociniomg';
```

I need to transform this $Urlcode in array, in PHP, anyone know?

Thanks to everyone now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`parse_str`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: $urlcode = 'nome=luiz&pais=brasil';

parse_str($urlcode, $output);
echo $output['nome'];

Comment: Yeah, that function is pretty sweet.

Comment: @Luiz, if this is the right answer, which it is, you should click the white checkmark, indicating that it's the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

use parse_str(), it does exactly what you want

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php